# Replace character between slashes

Tags: regex, perl

```
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/####_####_####_###_####_a.jpg
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/wefawf/vawvaw/a####_####_####_###_####.jpg
```

I'm trying to create a Regex that replaces the 'a' in between the last '/' and '.jpg' with an 'n'.

I'm completely lost right now. I'm using Perl and from what I understand it should be along these lines:

```
s/^.*\/.*$/n/g
```

... except I'm not sure where to put the 'a'.

Comment: / is a forwardslash and \ is a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

```
$foo =~ s?/a([^/]*.jpg)?/n$1?g;
```

Comment: Does that even compile?  Even fixing `~=` to `=~`, I then get 'substitution replacement not terminated`, admittedly with Perl 5.8.8.  Is it supposed to be using the `s{re1}(re2)` style alternative bracketing?  If so, doesn't it drop the last slash when the `a` immediately follows the slash, and doesn't it ignore the `a` anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

If there's guaranteed only one 'a', then Paul's answer will suffice, with a couple of small changes:

```
$foo =~ s|a([^/]*\.jpg)\Z|n$1|;
```

First, I have no '/' preceding the 'a'.  It's sufficient to specify that there are no '/'s between 'a' and '.jpg', and that allows for both of your examples (with the '/' present it only matched the second of your examples).  I also removed the '/g' modifier and added '\Z' to anchor the regex to the end of the string.  We only need the last match.

If there may be multiple 'a's between the final '/' and '.jpg', things get only slightly trickier:

```
while ($foo =~ s|(/[^/]*)a([^/]*\.jpg\Z)|$1n$2|) { }
```

Basically, while there are still 'a's between the final '/' and '.jpg', keep swapping 'a's for 'n's one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the first 'a' between the last '/' and '.jpg' with an 'n' (tested):

```
$ cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub a_with_n {
    shift;
    s!(.*/.*)a(.*\.jpg)!$1n$2!;
    return $_;
}

my @test_strings = (
    'http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/####_####_####_###_####_a.jpg',
    'http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/wefawf/vawvaw/a####_####_####_###_####.jpg'
);

foreach (@test_strings) {
    printf("%s\n", a_with_n($_));
}


$ ./test.pl 
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/####_####_####_###_####_n.jpg
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/wefawf/vawvaw/n####_####_####_###_####.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this replacement (matching multiple occurrences of "a"):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my $last = rindex ($_, "/");    # get index of last "/"
    substr ($_,$last) =~ s/a/n/g;   # change all "a" to "n" starting from last "/"
    print;
  }

__DATA__
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/####_####_####_###_###a#_aa.jpg
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/wefawf/vawvaw/a####_####_####_###_####.jpg
```

Output:

```
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/####_####_####_###_###n#_nn.jpg
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/wefawf/vawvaw/n####_####_####_###_####.jpg
```